# Here Data Client Spark Library is not compatible with new Hadoop Versions (guava version 19.0-jre vs. 27.0-jre)

Tags: apache-spark, guava

`"com.here.platform.data.client" %% "spark-support" % "1.9.11"` uses guava version `19.0-jre` (very old version)

Current Hadoop Versions uses guava version `27.0-jre` +.

Is it possible to update the guava version of the data client library to stay compatible with hadoop? (yes, this is a question to the here developer if THEY can update their library)

Comment: You'll have to try and see for yourself. It's probably not that hard to go through the Here library, search for Guava usages and see whether they're only using stable APIs that are present in the current version, too. On the other hand, you could try updating the Here library, looks like the newest is `1.11.21`.

Comment: Here Library ```1.11.21``` also uses guava version ```19.0```. And it is not about updating the version on my side. I have to work with one of the current Hadoop Versions and so I have to integrate guava ```27.0``` in my docker image. Excluding guava from the service and using the version from the docker image is also no solution for me.